Odata custom action in C# giving Page not found
I am new to odata and trying to follow the tutorial
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/webapi-8/fundamentals/routing-overview?tabs=net60
I am trying to create an action reachable on
http://localhost:5207/odata/Customers/Get12345
but it is giving "The localhost page can't be found"

The one option I came across is to add

[Route("odata/Customers/Get12345")] on top of the action, but I dont want this as I feel if "odata" changes I will have to make multiple changes and feel there could be better options.

Other option I came across is to use Action, but I am not able to make it work as I dont understand it completely. Can someone please help with the same.


var customersType = modelBuilder.EntitySet<Customer>("Customers").EntityType;
customersType.Collection.Action("Get12345")
    .ReturnsFromEntitySet<Customer>("Customers");

// Program.cs
// Program.cs
using Lab01.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData;
using Microsoft.OData.ModelBuilder;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var modelBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder(); 
modelBuilder.EntityType<Order>(); 
modelBuilder.EntitySet<Customer>("Customers");
// It means if you have an entity set named Customers based on Customer entity type
// Odata type returned here returns the data in the form of Customer entity type as is named as "Customers" in the odata context
// It indicates that this payload comes from Customer entity set

var customersType = modelBuilder.EntitySet<Customer>("Customers").EntityType;
customersType.Collection.Action("Get12345")
    .ReturnsFromEntitySet<Customer>("Customers");

builder.Services.AddControllers().AddOData(
    options => options.Select().Filter().OrderBy().Expand().Count().SetMaxTop(null).AddRouteComponents("odata", modelBuilder.GetEdmModel()));

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapControllers());
// Customers is being defined as the name of the entity set
// so seeing if changing the controller to Customer gives the data - No it does not give the data

app.Run();

CustomersController.cs
using Lab01.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Query;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Routing.Controllers;

namespace Lab01.Controllers
{
    public class CustomersController : ODataController
    {
        private static Random random = new Random();
        private static List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>(
            Enumerable.Range(1, 3).Select(idx => new Customer
            {
                Id = idx,
                Name = $"Customer {idx}",
                Orders = new List<Order>(
                    Enumerable.Range(1, 2).Select(dx => new Order
                    {
                        Id = (idx - 1) * 2 + dx,
                        Amount = random.Next(1, 9) * 10
                    }))
            }));

        [EnableQuery]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<Customer>> Get()
        {
            return Ok(customers);
        }

        [EnableQuery]
        public ActionResult<string> Get([FromRoute] int key)
        {
            var item = customers.SingleOrDefault(d => d.Id.Equals(key));

            if (item == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok("abcd");
        }

        // Create an action to be accessible at the odata endpoint for Get1234567


        // For this the endpoint localhost:5207/Customers
        // /Get12345 is working - But it is not Odata compatible as odata is not coming in response
        // The endpoint this is not working - "http://localhost:5207/odata/Customers/Get12345"
        [EnableQuery]
        public ActionResult<Customer> Get12345()
        {
            var item = customers.SingleOrDefault(d => d.Id.Equals(1));

            if (item == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(item);
        }

        [EnableQuery]
        [Route("odata/Customers/Get1234567")]
        public ActionResult<Customer> Get1234567()
        {
            return new Customer();
        }
    }
}

Customer.cs
namespace Lab01.Models
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public class Customer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    }
}

Order.cs
namespace Lab01.Models
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public class Customer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    }
}


The problem is that actions only support HttpPost request. To fix this, you need to mark your method with the [HttpPost] attribute.
In Microsoft documentation actions described like

Actions are a way to add server-side logic that is not easily defined
as CRUD (Create, Read, Update, and Delete) operations on entities. An
action can have side effects, which is why they are invoked with the
HTTP POST method. An action can target a single entity or a collection
of entities. In OData terminology, this is binding. You can also have
"unbound" actions, which are basically static operations on the OData
service.

[EnableQuery]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult<Customer> Get12345()
{
    ...
}

Also, be aware that entering the URL into the browser will result in an HttpGet request.
